# how can I simply benchmark my linux application

Tags: linux, performance

Imagine you write application, alternative to some existing version and you want to compare if it's more effective or not,

you can simply use `time` like

```
time yourcommand
time oldcommand
```

and compare the execution time to check some difference, but this isn't very detailed

Is there similar command to check more data? Such as memory usage, cpu utilization, cpu peak, memory peak etc...

Comment: What language ? Your after a profiler. Strace can give some food info in general but your after a dedicated profile

Comment: in this case it's c++ vs c,but I was looking rather for some simple command that do these basic, but most important measurements, which answer bellow perfectly covers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good implementation of `time` actually tells you a lot more than wallclock time. Most Linux systems have one, but Bash tends to obscure it in favor of its built-in time, so you have to call it as `/usr/bin/time`:

```
$ /usr/bin/time python -c "import numpy as np; np.empty(100000)"
0.12user 0.00system 0:00.13elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 12860maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+3777minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

That's CPU use, memory usage and several other statistics for a simple Python command. See the manpage `time(1)` for what `time` can do.

Comment: For memory usage, consider also using `pmap` or simply `cat /proc/$(pidof yourcommand)/maps` during execution of your benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single best way to do what you're talking about, as it depends a lot on your application, as well as what you wish to profile.

But [this post](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/profiling/) offers some suggestions on ways to profile Linux or a specific application, which may help you along the right direction.

You will likely find better answers if you can tell us more specifically what you're hoping to profile, which language(s) you're using, etc.